# Find most common property - cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way I can use cypher to derive the most common (and second most common) property value of a particular node type?

At the moment I am identifying the different values for the property:

```
MATCH(a:Label1)-[r:REL]->(b:Label2) RETURN DISTINCT b.prop;
```

And then counting them individually:

```
MATCH(a:Label1)-[r:REL]->(b:Label2) WHERE b.prop = "x" RETURN COUNT(x);
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am using Neo4j 3.0.0.

I'm not sure how to combine these queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as easy as :

```
MATCH (a:Label1)-[r:REL]->(b:Label2)
RETURN b.prop, count(*) as occurences
ORDER BY occurences DESC
LIMIT 2
```

You can read about automatic aggregation here : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks - I added order DESC to get the most common.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `keys()` function to get the properties from each matching node. This returns a collection of keys for that node. Unwind the collections and aggregate the counts for each property accross all matching nodes.

```
MATCH (a:Label1)-[r:REL]->(b:Label2)
UNWIND keys(b) as prop
RETURN prop, count(*) as num_props
ORDER BY num_props desc
```

Comment: oh - i see property value, not property key - sorry - poor reading on my part

Answer (score 2):

```
//
// Get patterns
MATCH (a:Label1)-[r:REL]->(b:Label2)
//
// Pass through all keys
UNWIND KEYS(b) as key
   //
   // Get patterns again
   MATCH (a:Label1)-[r:REL]->(b:Label2)
//
// Aggregating by title of the properties and its content
RETURN key as propName, b[key] as propValue, count(b[key]) as propRank
//
// Sort the largest property-value pairs first
ORDER BY propRank DESC
```

Comment: Please add commentary so that the user understands the answer, instead of being just a code dump, otherwise it's liable to be flagged for deletion.